# Array.fill function is not working in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using Array.fill() to print the star but the code shows only 1 star...]

```
import React from 'react'

function Rating(props) {
    const {rating, numReviews} = props;
    return (
        <div className="product_rating">
           {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_, _i) => (
              <p></p>
            ))
           }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rating;
```

Comment: copy/paste the code instead of uploading screenshots

Comment: The array is empty

Comment: Instead of images, it is better to copy/paste the actual code, and indent it using (I think) `control k`

Comment: Please post code, not images of code ...

Comment: What is `rating`?

Comment: rating contain a num...which is equal to 5...I also print the rating which shows 5 but when I use rating variable in array.fill()....then this is not working

Comment: Are you sure? While I might not do it this way, I don't immediately see a reason why this wouldn't return an array of the five paras.

Comment: It does @DaveNewton. Just tested it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPD: If the rating is a string use parseInt

```
    {Array(parseInt(rating))
      .fill()
      .map((_, _i) => (
        <p></p>
      ))}
```

Comment: Doesn't `Array.from` expect an array-like or iterable source? If `rating` is numeric this wouldn't do the same thing.

Comment: Without knowing what `rating` is, this ist just wild guessing ...

Comment: rating is a numeric value which showing 5  ...i print this <h1>{rating}</h1>...which gives me 5 ...but in Array.fill()  this is not working

Comment: @NavreetKaur Then it's likely it isn't actually what you think it is. Are you sure it's not a string? How does it fail? What browser (e.g., IIRC IE needs a polyfill)?

Comment: @NavreetKaur
I assume the rating is the string "5". Updated an answer